Android IT test gets idle 4 seconds
I have an android integration test that uses 4 seconds for do nothing:
Only thing I have is the logs:
    13:53:49.436 LifecycleMonitor                                          
Lifecycle status change: org.myapp.nema.StartupActivity@c0cd6ec in: DESTROYED 13:53:49.436 ActivityScenario
                                Update currentActivityStage to DESTROYED, currentActivity=null 13:53:53.051 
ProfileInstaller                                          Installing profile for org.myapp.nema.generic 13:53:54.931 
TestRunner  finished: test_set_backlight_down(org.myapp.nema.test.usecases.BacklightControllerTest) 13:53:54.934                                                           run finished: 1 tests, 0 failed, 0 ignored

As can be seen, during those seconds only log shown is ProfileInstaller                                          Installing profile for org.myapp.nema.generic does anyone know what it is
